# Domain of the integral function $F(x)=\int_2^x (1-\frac{\sin^2 t}{t})\, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have to study the integral function given by $F(x)=\int_2^x (1-\frac{\sin^2 t}{t})\, dt$.
First of all I have to determine the domain of $F(x)$. To to this I can observe that $f(t)=(1-\frac{\sin^2 t}{t})$ is definite and continous in $(-\infty, 0)\cup (0,+\infty)$. 
For the reason why the finite limit of the integral, that is $x_0\in 2$ is in $(0,+\infty)$, I want to study the behaviour of $f$ for $t\to 0^+$ in order to study the convergence of $\int_2^0 f(x) \, dx$.
To do this I have done the following:
$$\left(1-\frac{\sin^2 t}{t}\right) \sim 1-t \text{ for}\, t\to 0^+$$
And now since $\int_2^0 1-t\, dt$ is finite then also $\int_2^0 (1-\frac{\sin^2 t}{t})\, dt$ is convergent. So surely $(0,+\infty)\in \operatorname{Domain}_F$.

$\textbf{1 question}$: do you think my passages are right?
$\textbf{2 question}$: I have also to study the behaviour for $t\to 0^-$?

EDIT:
Someone states that my doubts are not clear. My doubts are summarized on the two question above. If you think that my attempt of work is a bit confused can you help me writing how can I find out the domain of $F$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only point that needs to be emphasized is that x must be finite.

Comment: yes and this is since the improper integral is divergent...and so what is the domain?

Comment: Moreover what's about my two questions?

Comment: For 2)  It is not necessary to distinguish $\to 0^+$ from $\to 0^-$.  For 1) it is correct, although a little wordy.  Domain for $F(x)$ is all finite $x$.

Comment: Maybe I have not understand...if I writhe that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ is not right?

Comment: R is fine for the domain of $F(x)$.  Suggestion - proofread your notes.  (writhe)

Comment: I have read my notes many times but I still have doub otherwise I would have not asked a question here

Comment: You need to define your doubt (as well as proofread your post!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(t)=1-\sin^2(t)/t$ for $t\neq 0$ and $f(t)=1$ for $t=0$, then $f$ is continuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there are two cases: either $x\geq 2$ or $x<2$.  If $x\geq 2$, then $f$ is continuous and bounded on $[2,x]$. If $x<2$, then $f$ is continuous and bounded on $[x,2]$. In both cases, $$\int_2^xf(t)dt\text{ and }\int_x^2f(t)dt=-\int_2^xf(t)dt$$ exist, since continuous functions on compact sets are integrable. It should follow that the domain of $F$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

You say you want to study the behavior of $f$ as $t$ approaches $0$ in order to study the convergence of $F(0)$. This is as simple as showing that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(t)=1$. Then you just continuously extend $f$ from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by defining $f(0)=1$, as I have done above.

Hopefully that clears things up and answers your question of how to find the domain of $F$.

Comment: Ok very thanks so if I continously extend in $0$ the function $f$ then $F$ will be defined and continous also in $0$, right?

Comment: @cely yes. that’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \Bigg[1-\frac{\sin ^2(t)}{t}\Bigg]\,dt=\int \Bigg[1-\frac {1-\cos(2t)}{2t}\Bigg]\,dt$$
$$I=t+\frac 12{\text{Ci}(2 t)}-\frac 12{\log (t)}+C$$ which is defined for any $t>0$. But, for small $t$, we have
$$I=\frac{1}{2} (\gamma +\log (2))+t-\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ So, $I$ is defined $\forall t \geq 0$.

But the [cosine integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) has the series expansion
$$\text{Ci}(x)=\gamma+\log(x)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {(-x^2)^k}{2k \,(2k)!}$$ then the logarithms disappear and the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ (just as you wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

Let's state some assumptions first. We are dealing here with Riemann integrals and that too proper ones (in contrast to improper Riemann integrals).

With this assumption the symbol $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ is defined for functions $f$ which are bounded on $[a, b] $. Further if $a=b$ the symbol is defined to be $0$ irrespective of nature of $f$. And if $a>b$ the symbol is defined as $-\int_b^a f(x) \, dx$.

In most cases the function $f$ is given in terms of a formula. When this is the case it is expected that the formula for $f(x) $ makes sense for all $x\in[a, b] $. If that's not the case then we need to dig deeper. If the formula for $f(x) $ makes sense for all $x\in[a, b] $  *except for a finite number of points* then there is absolutely no problem and we are at liberty to define $f$ at those points in any arbitrary manner whatsoever. This is because *the values of a function at a finite number of points neither affects Riemann integrability of the function nor the value of the integral (if it exists)*.

Based on this we see that the integrand $f(t) =1-\dfrac{\sin^2t}{t}$ is defined everywhere except at $f=0$. Defining $f(0)$ in any manner is ok and we don't care about it. Then $f$ is defined and bounded in any closed interval and moreover it has only one possible discontinuity, namely at $0$. Thus $f$ is Riemann integrable on any closed interval.

It follows that $F(x) =\int_2^x f(t) \, dt$ is defined for all real values of $x$ and hence the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb {R} $.

---

In particular you don't need to take limit of integrals here. That procedure is needed for improper Riemann integrals when either the function is unbounded or the interval of integration is unbounded or both are unbounded. For functions which are bounded on bounded intervals we don't need this limiting procedure.

Also for completeness sake one can't have a formula for the integrand undefined at at infinite number of points. If you get something like that then understand that there is no point talking about the Riemann integral of that integrand.

Comment: What I have not understood is a thing: the second fundamental integral calculus theorem states that if $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ then $F$ si continpus in $[a,b]$, so the continuity of $f$ in $[a,b]$, so in our case extending $f$ in $0$ is useful for the differentiability of $F$ and not for the domain, right?

Comment: @cely : yeah if the integrand $f$ is continuous then integral function $F$ is differentiable. But going further deep observe that this is just a sufficient condition. There are cases when integrand $f$ is discontinuous and yet $F$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thanks! Another thing: stating that "If the formula for f(x) makes sense for all x∈[a,b] except for a finite number of points then there is absolutely no problem and..." means that these points can be points where the integrand is not continous but for which the limit of the function at these points from  right and from left exist finite? So if $x<0$ I rewrite  in $[x,2]$ (there is $0$ where the integrand is not defined) but I can rewrite $\int_2^x=\int_0^2+\int_2^x$ and each one of the two integrals now it is the integral of a continous function.

Comment: @cely: there is no need for even the right or left limits to exist at those points. The existence of integral is controlled not by nature of discontinuities but rather by amount of discontinuities. The idea may be difficult to explain at your level, but roughly a bounded function is Riemann integrable on a closed interval *iff* its discontinuities on that interval *don't occupy too much space* of that interval. A finite number of discontinuities is fine. Even a countable number of discontinuities is ok.

Comment: @cely: the idea of "occupying space" is handled in a rigorous fashion using measure theory.

Comment: @cely: another thing to note about left right limits. If integrand $f$ has left limit $L$ at $c$ then integral $F$ has left derivative at $c$ and the value of this derivative is $L$. Same goes for right limit / right derivative. Thus your function $F$ is differentiable everywhere with $F'(x) =f(x), x\neq 0,F'(0)=1$.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the explanations! I'll surely reflect on these! you are one of the most helpful person I have ever "encountered" in this site!