# When a definition involving a function makes reference to real intervals, is it implicit that the function is defined for all values in that interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definition

Consider the following purposefully vague definition (a general structure taken from a book on **real-valued functions**):

> A function $f$ is **blah** on an interval, if for all $a$ in the interval, **something**.

When making arguments about this function, can I assume from the definition that $f$ must necessarily be defined (i.e. $\in \mathbb R$) for every object in the interval?

I ask this question because there are times where I am considering counter examples that have bad behaviors...but such bad behaviors require that $f$ not be defined at certain values. For example, let's say I want to know if  $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$ is **blah** on the interval $[0,4]$.

If it *is* the case that definitions resembling the above structure have the implicit understanding that $f$ must be defined for all values in that interval, then I can disregard counter examples like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$.

Comment: You could add the value of $ f $ at $ x=2$ by putting for example $ f(2)=0$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah would you agree that $f$ is necessarily defined for all values in that interval, though?

Comment: If we are talking about a function having some property on a given interval then a pre-requisite is that the function must be defined on that interval. In many examples the function is defined by a formula and the domain is not mentioned explicitly and the domain has to be inferred as largest possible subset of reals for which formula is valid.

Comment: Also see this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122141/72031 which deals with a related issue in context of integrals.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh cheers!